# Node.js re-usable code server-client

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, npm, requirejs

I'm doing some R&D on Node.js and so far I like it, I'm just curious on how I could re-use code in order to have some shared code between client and server.

A good example of that need would be Backbone.js which I installed with npm.

Currently I have a directory that looks like this:

```
app.js
    public/
    routes/
    views/
    node_modules/
    tests/
```

Obviously I use express.js and all my client-side code is under `public` folder where `css`, `images`, `js` files are located.

So how I could have a model in backbone which I could use it in both server and back?

Also I used to use JavaScript AMD with Require.js in order to structure and modulize my application, I got used to it and I tend to like it I saw require.js is available via npm but now that I installed it I'm not sure how I cal use it in client-side since I used to have something like this: `<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/Require/require.js">` but since require.js is installed via npm it is isn't under public folder so I can't see any possible way to load it.

Thanks

Comment: `public/models` , `public/collections`, `public/views`, just put the backbone stuff in public. As for re-using require, consider using modul8 or browserify instead

Comment: @Raynos if I have for instance `var Backbone = require('backbone');` in the model then when I will try to load this JS file it will throw an exception that the `require` method is not defined, or it will messed up with require.js which I use on my client-side so how I could have a *hybrid* model so I could use it on both client and server side since I use require.js on client as a result my scripts start with `define([...` that's why I was thinking to use requireJS on both sides.

Comment: Don't use requireJS on both sides. Use node on node and use browserify/modul8 on the client.

Comment: Ok I got that, but seriously why not require.js not even on client-side? I mean how bad is it?

Comment: http://tomdale.net/2012/01/amd-is-not-the-answer/

Comment: @Raynos hi again, I ended up using browserify which is awesome by the way, but I now face an issue, if you could check it out **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948804)** I would appreciate it a lot! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a symbolic link (ln -s) to require.js from the public folder.

I think you can just place the backbone model in public as well and then use requirejs both on the server and the client to load the same file.

Comment: I would avoid requirejs on the server, just use node's `require`

Comment: True, I think you can also do some wrapping that makes a module work with both requirejs and node, I can't find it right now.

Comment: Yes you can, it's a pain in the ass though, just don't use requireJS and use modul8 or browserify instead.

Comment: Hello, I like the approach of symlinks I'm just curious why should I avoid requireJS on the server?

Comment: Just to mention that ln -s didn't workout but ln -P worked like a charm I don't know why soft link didn't worked out but hard link did the job and its cool now :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is somewhat late, but I just wanted to add that instead of using browserify on the client side, you can use https://npmjs.org/package/define on the server side, which lets you define modules in AMD-style, but require them with node's require()