# Node.js require() vs RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, requirejs

Hello with RequireJS I can set a base path like this: `base : './app/'` so when I am in `./app/foo/bar/` for example and I have a script where I use `require('foo');` RequireJS then would search for `./app/foo.js` and not in `node_module` folder or in `./app/foo/bar/foo.js` this comes handy when you have a kind of structure where it would be much cleaner for you as a developer to see the dependencies instead of having `../../foo.js`. I could have `./app/foo.js` and `./app/foo/foo.js` and `./app/foo/bar/foo.js` it would be much more cleaner to have:

```
require('foo');
require('foo/foo');
require('foo/bar/foo');
```

rather than:

```
require('../../foo');
require('../foo');
require('./foo');
```

Now you could say why not change the name and not have foo everywhere, let's say that we can't for any reason…

Another lack of feature that I see in node's require method against RequireJS is the ability of setting path mapping, if I have a directory named `./app/super-sized-directory-name/` in RequireJS I could simply do `'big-dir' : 'super-sized-directory-name'` and then I could simply use `require('./app/big-dir/foo')` with Node.js's require method this is not possible as far as I know…

Comment: [modul8](https://github.com/clux/modul8) supports this feature through domains but the syntax isn't compliant with node. I believe browserify only supports relative file paths

Comment: @Raynos hello! Thanks for your reply! I changed the question to make my point more clear, I will take a look on modul8 from first glance it seems more complicated than browserify, what I like in browserify is that it compiles on the fly the script and accepts coffee too which is very cool

Comment: @Raynos I checked again modul8 and read it's docs more carefully I believe it is very cool and maybe what I'm looking for! I will test it now :)

Comment: modul8 deals with coffee. As for on the fly compiling, build a small [watch script](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim/blob/master/build.js#L30) if by on the fly you mean middleware, don't do that. Pre-compile and serve statically.

Comment: In overal modul8 fits my needs better than browserify but I have some issues with npm and modul8, when I try to use `require('npm::backbone');` I get `DEBUG: Error: modul8 failed to require npm module underscore` probably because backbone requires underscore as submodule but I have it there as submodule of backbone module...

Comment: `require('backbone')` should work if npm installed correclty. If not raise a github issue for modul8.

Comment: @Raynos I did as you said, after I saw that I'm following the API correctly I raised an issue **[here](https://github.com/clux/modul8/issues/11)** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--alias, -a    Register an alias with a colon separator: "to:from"
             Example: --alias 'jquery:jquery-browserify'
```

You can register aliases with browserify, so that covers your renaming.

As for your rooted absolute paths, that can't really be done. As mentioned `modul8` has a namespacing mechanism to solve this.

I would recommend you pong SubStack in #stackvm on freenode and ask him directly.

Comment: Do browserify or modul8 work asynchronously? If not it seems to me that requirejs remains at least the right to be used for modules used in the browser.

Comment: @Bruiser they work asynchronously, meaning they do not block. They work by preloading all the modules

Comment: thanks, so you would prefer using browserify over requirejs in a node project?

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not help you, but I believe the Dojo Frameworks AMD Loader is API compatible with RequireJS and providing you are using a new microkernel does not pollute the global namespace.

I believe it only has `require()` and `define()` in the global namespace now.

Anyway their method of dealing with this is to do something like:

```
require(["dojo/node!util"], function(util){
    // Module available as util
});
```

The documentation is at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/node.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [uRequire](http://urequire.org) which provides a 'bridge' between nodejs `require` and AMD `define` modules, without reinventing the wheel (it is build on top of the two standards). It basically converts modules from AMD or commonJS format to the other format or [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/) that runs smoothly on both nodejs & the browser.

It is also translating dependency paths with [flexible path conventions](http://urequire.org/flexible-path-conventions), so you can have either `'../../foo'` or `'bar/foo'` depending on which makes more sense at the point you are at.

Your AMD or UMD modules are loaded asynchronously on browser (using AMD/requireJs or other AMD loader) and on node the asynchronous `require(['dep1', 'dep2'], function(dep1,dep2){...})` is also simulated.